# Calculations of elements in matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I calculate number of non zero elements of a strictly upper or lower triangular matrix of order (n x n)?

Comment: Maybe simply $2S+n=n^2$ corresponding to upper + lower + diagonal = total matrix

Comment: Do you have any more assumptions about what the matrix could be?

Answer (score 1):

For a strictly upper triangular matrix,

$$U=\begin{bmatrix}0&a_{12}&\ldots&0\\0&0&\ldots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&\ldots&0\end{bmatrix}$$

we have $n$ zeroes on the diagonal, $n-1$ zeroes on the sub-diagonal and so on till we have only $1$ zero at the bottom left corner. The number of zero entries is **at-least**
$$
n + (n - 1) + \ldots + 1
= \frac{n (n + 1)}{2},
$$
at-least, because the entries above the diagonal can also be zero. The number of non-zero entries is **at-most**
$$
n^2 - \frac{n (n + 1)}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}.
$$

It is easy to see that the case of strictly lower triangular matrices is similar.